# Can't run any jQuery plugin inside my ASP.NET MVC application, what would be the cause?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

These days I went through difficult times, I tried to implement a jQuery plugin called elevate zoom but couldn't succeed thought this might be the problem with jQuery plugin and switched to implement Cloud Zoom but had no luck yet. I placed all the scripts needed by this plugin into my view and also the CSS as you can see my view code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Zoom";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



    <title>Cloud Zoom</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <!-- Include jQuery. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include Cloud Zoom CSS. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/cloudzoom.css" />

    <!-- Include Cloud Zoom script. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/cloudzoom.js"></script>

    <!-- Call quick start function. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){CloudZoom.quickStart();})
    </script>

    <!-- Setup the zoomImage property to point to the big image. -->
    <img class="cloudzoom" src="~/images/small/image1.jpg"
         data-cloudzoom="zoomImage: '~/images/large/image1.jpg'" />
```

Layout code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**Final Generated HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Zoom - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">






    <title>Cloud Zoom</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <!-- Include jQuery. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include Cloud Zoom CSS. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/cloudzoom.css" />

    <!-- Include Cloud Zoom script. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/cloudzoom.js"></script>

    <!-- Call quick start function. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){CloudZoom.quickStart();})
    </script>

    <!-- Setup the zoomImage property to point to the big image. -->
    <img class="cloudzoom" src="/images/small/image1.jpg"
         data-cloudzoom="zoomImage: '~/images/large/image1.jpg'" />





        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2016 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Firefox","requestId":"c6cb955b8169466e9a82c8082a334502"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:6214/1d36907a16cf4beea1f3582a362b6719/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$(function(){ CloudZoom.quickStart(); })`?

Comment: @GeneR yes didn't worked!

Comment: Do you have errors in browser console?

Comment: What is in the `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`? And what is the exact error message?

Comment: @GeneR don't have any error in the console i use firebug!

Comment: @Anton there is no error message, see updated question for the _Layout.

Comment: You should include scripts in `_Layout` and do not duplicate `html`, `head` and `body` tags

Comment: @GeneR shall i remove the body and head tags in my view? i tried to put scripts in layout but no result though.

Comment: Check answer, your view must contain only `<img.../>`

Comment: Can you please show  what files you are including in bundles - @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap") 

It may be jquery conflict I want to see bundle file code to clerify

Comment: A 2 cent Tip 

Try to remove modernizr script inclusion on line below 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

Comment: Try To Put This line of Code at the end of File below closing of body tag </body>

<!-- Call quick start function. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){CloudZoom.quickStart();})
    </script>

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla thanks but didn't worked.

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla, that is not necessary, look at the cloud zoom website.

Comment: @Anton it's not only with this plugin i get it not working with any jquery plugin.

Comment: @NaserDostdar There might be a single JS error which stops the JS execution and then nothing works. Have you checked the browser console? Please, see my comment under my question and try to answer the questions.

Comment: @NaserDostdar, please, one IMPORTANT thing, could you please provide the final HTML generated by the MVC code? That might be actually helpful.

Comment: Do you have this plugin working in html code . I am having an online html code where it is working . Is it working in html code on your side instead in mvc

Comment: @Anton   Yes the code in html works super fine but not the view, where do you want me to paste you the final generated html?

Comment: @NaserDostdar, ideally in the question :).

Comment: @Anton see the updated question.

Comment: @NaserDostdar , good that, we have something to start with. Thx for posting the HTML.

Comment: @Anton i really need help on this would be much happy if you help me to overcome this. :)

Comment: @NaserDostdar 1) Please, take a look at mine answer once again - I have updated it in the meantime. It would be good to use the sections so the CSS is inserted in the head tag of the layout and script go down. 2) Where does the Visual studio browser link (at the very bottom) come from? Can you remove it?

Comment: I got Cloud Zoom Working in Asp.net MVC4 . Do you want me to send that to you

Comment: @Anton gimme a min i will do it.

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla yes sure. you can send it to naserdtr@gmail.com

Comment: I am not exactly u sign you code but code zoom is working on my side let me know how can i send you code or you want me to put that in answer

Comment: Ok just sending it in 1 min

Comment: @Anton i tried your answer same result nothing changes, couldn't manage to get where this browser link comes from.

Comment: @Anton let me share a story on this. when i wanted to use the elevate zoom i couldn't run it either but when i pasted these http://jsfiddle.net/y3vMt/ pieces of code it was running for the very first time and when i clicked it didn't work either.

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla you can't send a solution via email please upload it somewhere as zip.

Comment: Yes i am sending it through send6

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla waiting....

Comment: sorry for waiting its uploading

Comment: @NaserDostdar, I just checked the Visual Studio browser link. Seems to be innocent - it just allows you to refresh the page from within the Visual Studio environment. I just wanted to be sure it is not the culprit but seems like it is not.

Comment: @NaserDostdar, ah, crap, maybe I know what is the problem, give me a second to update my answer.

Comment: @Anton Good to hear that. :)

Comment: @NaserDostdar Files Sent

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla many thanks let me check.

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla can't believe that yours is working even here in my system too. Thanks a lot now i can find what is wrong with my solutions. Thankkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk you!

Comment: @NaserDostdar, ok, the answer is updated. The large image URL in the final generated HTML is wrong as the `~` character stays in the URL. But such an URL is of course not valid.

Comment: @NaserDostdar , My pleasure if its working for you that's great I will write the code for the files in the answer please accept that as answer if it works for you

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla just waiting for your answer. :)

Comment: @NaserDostdar I posted the answer

Comment: @NaserDostdar , Can you please accept my accept if it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

**_Layout.cshtml Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
*{margin:0px;padding:0;list-style-type:none;}
body{background:#E9F0F5;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-    size:13px;margin:0px;padding:0px;}
html{background-color:#E9F0F5;}
img{border:none;}
h3{font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#333;letter-    spacing:1px;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;}
p{margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;line-height:22px;}
.demo{margin:0 auto;width:600px;}
.tickul li{line-height:24px;}
/* zoom-section */
.zoom-section{clear:both;margin-top:20px;}
*html .zoom-section{display:inline;clear:both;}
.zoom-desc{float:left;margin-left:10px;width:310px;margin-bottom:20px;}
.zoom-small-image{border:4px solid #CCC;float:left;margin-bottom:20px;}
.zoom-tiny-image{border:1px solid #CCC;margin:0px;}
.zoom-tiny-image:hover{border:1px solid #C00;}
</style>

<link href="~/Content/css/cloud-zoom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <div class="demo">


                @RenderBody()
     </div>
</body>
```

**Zoom.cshtml View Code**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Zoom";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="zoom-section">        
    <div class="zoom-small-image">
        <a href='~/Content/images/bigimage00.jpg' class = 'cloud-zoom' id='zoom1' rel="adjustX:10, adjustY:-4"><img src="~/Content/images/smallimage.jpg" alt='' title="Optional title display" /></a></div>
    <div class="zoom-desc">
        <h3></h3>       
        <p><a href='~/Content/images/bigimage00.jpg' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' title='Red' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: '~/Content/images/smallimage.jpg' "><img class="zoom-tiny-image" src="~/Content/images/tinyimage.jpg" alt = "Thumbnail 1"/></a>

        <a href='~/Content/images/bigimage01.jpg' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' title='Blue' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: ' ~/Content/images/smallimage-1.jpg'"><img class="zoom-tiny-image" src="~/Content/images/tinyimage-1.jpg" alt = "Thumbnail 2"/></a>                  
        <a href='~/Content/images/bigimage02.jpg' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' title='Blue' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: '~/Content/images/smallimage-2.jpg' "><img class="zoom-tiny-image" src="~/Content/images/tinyimage-2.jpg" alt = "Thumbnail 3"/></a></p>

</div>
</div><!--zoom-section end-->
  <div class="zoom-section">
    <div class="zoom-small-image">
        <a href='~/Content/images/bigimage03.jpg' class='cloud-zoom' rel="tint:'#ff0000',tintOpacity:0.5,smoothMove:5,zoomWidth:480,adjustY:-4,adjustX:10"><img src="~/Content/images/smallimage-3.jpg" title="Optional Title Text" alt='' /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="zoom-desc">
```

```
<div class="zoom-section">
    <div class="zoom-small-image">
        <a href='~/Content/images/bigimage04.jpg' class='cloud-zoom' rel="position:'inside',showTitle:false,adjustX:-4,adjustY:-4"><img src="~/Content/images/smallimage-4.jpg" title="Your caption here" alt=''/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="zoom-desc">

</div>
</div><!--zoom-section end-->

<div class="zoom-section">
    <div class="zoom-small-image">
        <a href='~/Content/images/bigimage01.jpg' class='cloud-zoom' title="Your caption here" rel="softFocus: true, position:'anypos', smoothMove:2"><img src="~/Content/images/smallimage-1.jpg" alt='' /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="zoom-desc" style="position:relative">
        <div id="anypos" style="position:absolute;top:-128px; left: 128px;width:356px;height:256px;"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

**HomeController.cs Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Cloudzoom.Controllers
{
 public class HomeController : Controller
{

       public ActionResult Zoom()
    {
        return View();
    }




    }
}
```

CloudZoom Function is called in cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js File

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-    gallery').CloudZoom()});
```

Comment: Thanks, Would you be available if i get any question about this?

Comment: Where did you call the Cloud zoom function?

Comment: @NaserDostdar  was on commute to home ,Yes sure I am available , please ask your question . Let me check for cloud zoom function

Comment: @NaserDostdar Cloud Zoom Function is called in js file at very starting point below 

See cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js file in JS Folder under Content Folder . They Called the function on classes used in a href in view 

    $(document).ready(function(){$('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-    gallery').CloudZoom()});

Comment: Dear Heemanshu, would you please just do me a favor? Please write a solution for Cloud Zoom with Thumbelina Cloud Zoom slider. Would you do it for me? i don't really know how to work with javascript and jquery.

Comment: Ok Sure , I suggest you to create new question for that so that I also help other user with relevant title and details . I am in IST time that's why its late here . i will make that solution and will send that to you son tomorrow

Comment: Did it bro, Thanks for your efforts. just got ready to go with my application.

Answer (score 1):

Well, at first look it occurs to me that you actually nested `<html>` inside of the `<body>` tag. That is simply wrong.

Also look at this part of your code:

```
data-cloudzoom="zoomImage: '~/images/large/image1.jpg'"
```

The image URL remains untranslated, the tilda charcter `~` stays in the final generated HTML which is wrong. It should be probably:

```
<img class="cloudzoom" src="@Url.Content("~/images/small/image1.jpg")"
         data-cloudzoom="zoomImage: '@Url.Content(~/images/large/image1.jpg")'" />
```

**Layout should look like this:**
Please, notice the `@RenderSection` calls.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @RenderSection("stylesheets", required: false)
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**View should look like this:**
Please, notice the sections.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Zoom";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section stylesheets {
    <!-- Include Cloud Zoom CSS. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/cloudzoom.css" />
}

@section scripts {
    <!-- Include jQuery. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include Cloud Zoom script. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/cloudzoom.js"></script>
}

<!-- Call quick start function. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    CloudZoom.quickStart();
</script>

<!-- Setup the zoomImage property to point to the big image. -->
<img class="cloudzoom" src="@Url.Content("~/images/small/image1.jpg")"
         data-cloudzoom="zoomImage: '@Url.Content("~/images/large/image1.jpg")'" />
```

Comment: didn't worked! See updated question if you mean like that.

Comment: @NaserDostdar, I would love to help you but I need more than "didn't work" feedback. Any errors in the browser console? Have you checked in the browser's developer tools whether all the JS files and CSS files were loaded? Are you sure that jQuery was not loaded twice? Did the images loaded?

Comment: The images loaded successfully and i don't get any error but the main function which is zooming is not working at all. i mean when i mouse over on the image it is not zooming

Comment: and jquery loaded once not twice.

Comment: Couldn't get it working even now, i suppose there is fatal error which can't get this running, heemo sent me a working solution i'll change my solution regarding to that then will update. Many many thanks for your effort bro. wish me best of luck.